# Select objects based on the key in hash using jq

Tags: json, jq

I'd love to select objects based on the key in the hash, but I want the original object format back. How can I achieve this?

**original**

```
{
  "google.com": {
    "http": {
      "dest_url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "http://github.com"
    }
  },
  "aaa.com": {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://github.com"
    }
  },
  "bbb.com": {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://microsoft.com"
    }
  },
   "ccc.com": {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://.com"
    }
  }
}
```

**should be**

```
{
  "google.com": {
    "http": {
      "dest_url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "http://github.com"
    }
  },
  "bbb.com": {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://microsoft.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried it with `to_entries[] | select (.key == "google.com" or .key == "bbb.com") | [.key, .value]` but it eneded like this. I'm sure `[.key, .value]` part is wrong but I'm stuck on how I can workaround this.

```
[
  "google.com",
  {
    "http": {
      "dest_url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "http://github.com"
    }
  }
]
[
  "bbb.com",
  {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://microsoft.com"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with_entries(…)`, which is a shortcut to `to_entries | map(…) | from_entries`, which in turn decomposes the object into an array of key/value representations `to_entries`, modifies each item within that array `map`, and converts it back into the original structure `from_entries`.

```sh
jq 'with_entries(select(.key == "google.com" or .key == "bbb.com"))'
```

```json
{
  "google.com": {
    "http": {
      "dest_url": "http://stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "http://github.com"
    }
  },
  "bbb.com": {
    "https": {
      "dest_url": "https://microsoft.com"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PHD4Vc5Rrb)